# Recursively scan specific folders for a file in ruby

Tags: ruby, recursion, directory

I'm trying to recursively scan specific folders and search a specific file.

In the root folder (e.g., C:\Users\Me), I would like to scan just the folders called my* (so, the folders that start with the letters 'my' + whatever), then see if there is files .txt and store the first line in a variable.

For the scan i'm trying this code, but without succeed

```
require 'find'

pdf_file_paths = []
path_to_search = ['C:\Users\Me'];

Find.find('path_to_search') do |path|
    if path =~ /.*\.txt$/
        #OPEN FILE
end
```

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to look in 'C:\Users\Me\not_my_folder\myfolder' path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do as below :

```
first_lines_of_each_file = []
Dir.glob("C:/Users/Me/**/my**/*.txt",File::FNM_CASEFOLD) do |filepath|
  File.open(filepath,'rb') { |file| first_lines_of_each_file << file.gets }
end
```

`File::FNM_CASEFOLD` constant would search all the directories and files using *case insensitive* search. But if you want case sensitive search, then don't need use the second argument `File::FNM_CASEFOLD`.

If you have directories organized as

```
C:/Users/Me/
|- my_dir1/
    |- a.txt
    |- my_dir2/
        |- foo.txt
        |- baz.doc
|- my_dir3/
    |- biz.txt
```

- `Dir.glob("C:/Users/Me/**/my**/*.txt"` will give you all the .txt files. As the search is here recursive.
- `Dir.glob("C:/Users/Me/my**/*.txt"` will give you only the .txt files, that resides inside the directory, which are direct children of `C:/Users/Me/`. That's only files you will get are `a.txt`, `biz.txt`.

Comment: Does `my**` need two stars? Unfortunately it doesn't make selective recursion

Comment: @BroiSatse Yes.. `**` matches directories, and `*` matches files.

Comment: @BroiSatse It does.. As I ran this code in my machine and it works as expected.

Comment: Just tried to run `Dir['<my_rails_root>/a**/docs']`. It should give me `<my_rails_root>/app/assets/docs` folder path - it didn't.

Comment: Yep - It is returned when run with `Dir['<my_rails_root>/a*/a*/docs']`. It seems like `*` is just a placeholder matching anything and it doesn't matter whether this is a folder or file. `**` is a special bit which matches all the folders recursively, but it doesn't work if placed with other characters. The code above will match all the folders starting with my, but they might be in non-my folders as well to match (`C:/User/Me/foo/my-foo/` will match)

Comment: @BroiSatse I clarified it again.

Comment: In the line
    File.open(path,'r') { |file| Array[index[1]] << file.gets }
I would like to use an array to store the line, using the index[1] as index for the array (e.g., index[1] == 7). This code does not work due to index[1]. How can I write it to make it work?

Comment: @user3472065 what is `index[1]` ?

Comment: index[i] is an array 
e.g.: index = Array.new(1000,"7");
It contains numbers that I would like to use as index for the Array[] where the line is store

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
lines = Dir.glob("#{path}/**/my*/*.txt").map do |filename|
  File.open(filename) do |f|
    f.gets
  end
end
```

`Dir.glob` is similar to the `glob` executable on a *nix machine. This also works on Windows. `gets` gets the first line. Ensure that you use a [forward slash even for a Windows machine](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Dir.html#method-c-glob).

Comment: Ah! Sorry, missed that `my*`

Comment: `File.open(filename).gets` is not acceptable.. as none of the files, you are closing..

Comment: I was hoping `open` takes care of that :/ The source code suggests auto-closing happens only when a block is passed in. My mistake.

Comment: This won't do a recursive search.

Comment: True. Made some changes and tested them. However, this makes it slow :/

Comment: @BroiSatse `**` needs to be preceded in the expression `**/my*/*`.It then start search recursively.

Comment: Your expression now perfect.. :)

Comment: @ArupRakshit - But it then selects all the subfolders, we only want to check folder starting with `my`. Expression `**/my*` will search folder `foo/mysql` which shouldn't be searched because of `foo`.

Comment: @BroiSatse OP didn't mention although clearly, that if he/she want to search recursively any folders start with `my`, starting from `C:/Users/Me/`. If OP wants recursive then `**` needs, other wise not needed.

Comment: @ArupRakshit - `I'm trying to recursively scan specific folders`. It is not very clear I agree. However option with searching recursively using some folder pattern is much more interesting. :)

Comment: Sorry if the question is not so clear :)
I have this tree
C:/Users/Me/
|- my_1/
    |- a.txt
|- yyyy/
|- my_2/
    |- biz.txt
|- zzzz/

I wanna check ONLY in the folders my_* if there is the file .txt
I'm using this solution:
    Find.find(path_to_search) do |path|
 blocks = path.split('/')
 if ((blocks[1] <=> "my_000") == 1 &&  (blocks[1] <=> "my_999") == -1)
        if blocks[2] =~ /.*\.txt$/
 File.open(path,'r') { ...

This works, but it is not so efficient.
I tried this solution:
    lines = Dir.glob("C:/Users/Me/tc*/*.conf").map do |filepath|
but it seems that in filepath there is nothing

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is the cleanest solution, but you can try:

```
def find_files(file_name, root_path, folder_pattern = nil)
  root_path = File.join(root_path, '')
  paths = Dir[File.join(root_path, '**', file_name)]
  paths.keep_if! {|p| p.slice(path.size, p.size).split('/').all? {|s| s =~ folder_pattern}} if folder_pattern
end

find_files('C:/Users/Me', 'find_me.txt', /my.*/)
```